# JS comportamiento inverso del operador ||

Tags: javascript, condiciones

### Preámbulo / contexto

El operador `||` puede ser de ayuda algunas veces pues si cierto objeto tiene un valor *falsy* (e. g. `false`, `0`, `null`, `undefined`...) con este operador podemos dar un valor por defecto o inclusive controlar la ejecución del programa. Por ejemplo

```
const hola = 0;
const noPuedeSer0 = hola || 1; // toma el valor 1
```

El código anterior se puede escribir con un if ternario

```
const hola = 0;
const noPuedeSer0 = hola ? hola : 1; // toma el valor 1
```

Formalmente el operador `||` va a retornar el primer valor *truthy* que se encuentre, empezando de izquierda a derecha. Esta es la naturaleza de [Short-circuit evaluation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/short-circuit-evaluation-in-javascript)

### Pregunta

¿Existe algún operador que tenga el comportamiento inverso?

Es decir que evalúe si el valor es *falsy* y si lo es, elija ese valor, de lo contrario que elija el segundo valor. Por ejemplo

```
const id = undefined;
const parsedId = id <operador mágico> parseId(id);
```

En el caso anterior, `parsedId` debe ser `undefined`. Pero si tenemos este otro código

```
const id = "123";
const parsedId = id <operador mágico> parseId(id);
```

`parsedId` debe ser lo que sea que `parseId("123")` retorne.

Con un if ternario sería así

```
const id = "123";
const parsedId = id ? parseId(id) : id;
```

#### Lo que he intentado / pensado

- Invertir el valor falsy (`!id || parseId(id)`) pero regresaría un booleano
- Usar otro operador lógico (de hecho aquí está la respuesta, es muy sencillo, no lo pensé al momento de escribir la pregunta)
- `if`: `id ? parseId(id) : id`

Pero creo que estaría padre poder hacerlo sin un condicional explícito.

Gracias.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Puedes usar el `Y` lógico (*and*):

```js
const hola = 1;
const haDeSer0 = hola && 0; // toma el valor 0

console.log( haDeSer0 );
```

Si lo usas con varios operandos, devolverá `false` si cualquier de los operandos es `false`; o, dicho de otra forma, devolverá el primer valor `false` que encuentre.

```js
console.log( true && true && true && false );
```

**Complemento**

Formalmente `&&` retornará el primer valor *falsy* que encuentre. Si no encuentra ninguno, retornará el último argumento evaluado.

```js
const id = "123";

// si todos los elementos son truthy, regresa el último
console.log(id && (id + "456") && (id + "789"));

// y regresa el primer elemento falsy que se encuentre (de izquierda a derecha)
console.log(id && undefined && (id + "456"));
console.log(id && null && false && (id + "456"));
```

De hecho, como curiosidad, JavaScript en el `if` evalúa *truthy* y *falsy* values, en lugar de solamente `true` y `false`

Comment: Utilizar solo ````&&```` no funcionará, tu respuesta está sesgada al uso de 1 que es validado como ````true````.  Si defines ````const hola = null;```` va a retornar ````null```` y no ````0````.

Comment: Oh rayos, tienes toda la razón. Hasta ahorita que leo tu respuesta veo que era en extremo sencillo. No sé porqué no me di cuenta antes. No lo intenté porque creí que && casteaba el argumento a booleano pero me doy cuenta que no. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Primero que todo hay que entender como funciona el operador `||`.

Este operador irá ejecutando/comprobando/avanzando en las condiciones hasta que encuentre una que sea verdadera, de encontrarla cortará su ejecución ahí.

```js
let execute = doFalse() || doTrue() || doTrue()


function doTrue(){
  console.log("Execute is true")
  return true
}

function doFalse(){
  console.log("Execute false")
  return false
}
```

Ahora, también está el operador `|`, que a diferencia de su hermano `||` ejecutará todo y luego retornará la evaluación.

```js
let execute = doFalse() | doTrue() | doTrue()


function doTrue(){
  console.log("Execute is true")
  return true
}

function doFalse(){
  console.log("Execute false")
  return false
}
```

**Este comportamiento es lo mismo para el** `&&`.

Teniendo esto en cuenta podemos abarcar tu problema, dado que js es un lenguaje bastante peculiar con las validaciones y tipado como en el siguiente ejemplo:

```js
console.log("2+2 es: ", 2+2)
console.log("'2'+'2' es: ", '2'+'2')
console.log("2+2-2 es: ", 2+2-2)
console.log("'2'+'2'-'2' es: ", '2'+'2'-'2')
```

hay que tener en cuenta que la validación que se lleve a cabo debe estar bien estructurada para cortar el flujo, lamentablemente no hay un operador mágico pero puedes hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```js
let id = "123";
let parsedId = Number.isInteger(id) && id || parseId(id)
console.log("id =>", typeof(parsedId), parsedId)

id = 123;
parsedId = Number.isInteger(id) && id || parseId(id)
console.log("id =>", typeof(parsedId), parsedId)

function parseId(value){
  return parseInt(value)
}
```

**Realmente queda más limpio utilizar un operador ternario o encapsular dicha comprobación en una función.**

Entiendo que tu problema va más allá de los ejemplos puestos, porque si ese es el caso, simplemente utiliza `parseInt()`.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, sí era muy sencillo con el operador `&&`